# Saving Files in to the memory/virtual file C#

Tags: c#, memory, save, virtual

Is there any possibilities to save a file to a virtual folder or something. 
I use a method, which needs a string(path,where to save the file) as parameter to save the content. But i just want to save the file into the memory.Can I programmatically create a virtual folder/path?

Comment: Are you asking how to provide a path to a method you cannot modify such that no file is actually created on disk, but than can still be accessed via the path?

Comment: Right!. I have to save the file, because this is the only way how my object can be refreshed. But I don't want to save this to my disk. So i have to call this method to force my object to refresh.

Comment: I don't have written the method, which I have to use. It is from a libary, which I am using.

Comment: What lib would that be?

Comment: if you're using a 3rd party lib and can't modify the method, wouldn't the simplest solution be saving the file to a TEMP folder and deleting it after you're done with it?

Comment: No, I cant modify the lib. Thats my problem. And I was looking for solution without a temp file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your component want to recevice a file, you need a file on your HDD/SSD. In those cases, i prefer to use the APP-Data folder and create a sub directory in it. It is accessable over: `Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData`.

To come back to your question, it is not possible. Because the method you want to use, will take the os file system.

The only in memory solution would be, if there is an overload which accept a `MemoryStream` or just a `Stream`.